# python : selenium need parameter text using Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The HTML code is

```
<div class="_4w5j">
    <strong>
        <span>username</span>
    </strong>
    <span class="_-kj">—</span>
    <span class="_4w5k">
        <i class="img sp_4YfKd3lpYjo sx_5f57b1">
            <u>5 star</u>
        </i>
    </span>
    <span>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
</div>
```

1. I need the text "username" inside strong/spam It is works for me the code is

x= i.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_4w5j"]/strong')

```
for d in x:
    print d.text
```

It's print the correct result

I need the text of 'x'inside the span[3] 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
the below code also works good.

Question:

I need the text inside the u tag '5 star'. I used the below code but it prints the empty result.

```
y= i.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_4w5j"]/descendant::u')
for d in y:
    print d.text
```

I tried this also

```
y= i.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_4w5j"]/span[2]/i/u')
for d in y:
    print d.text
```

Not working for me. Please help me . Thanks in advance

```
<a class="uiLinkSubtle" href="/sherryl.cheary/activity/10152833559161998">
<abbr class="timestamp" data-utime="1419713801" title="Saturday, December 27, 2014 at 12:56pm">about a month ago</abbr>
</a>
```

I need the text inside the title but the below code sh

```
z= i.find_elements_by_xpath('//a/descendant::abbr/@title')
for dd in z:
    print dd.text
```

Its shows the error called " web element has no attr title or some thing wrong in xpath"

Comment: can u try with xpath: `//span class='_4w5k'` and then do element.text?

Comment: and for second part can you do use xpath: `//abbr[@class='timestamp']` and then call `get_attribute("title")`. I have never worked in python, so please check the signature of get_attribute method. Thanks

Comment: the xpath shows Error   //span class='_4w5k' is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement

Comment: sorry my mistake `"//span[@class='_4w5k']"`. Just forgot to put square brackets.

Comment: use css selectors, xpaths are not stable at all. To find <u elem you can use next selector : "._4w5j > i > u"

Comment: @VivekSingh //abbr[@class='timestamp'] is working fine let me check about the next one

Comment: @VivekSingh Still generating a empty result

Comment: @AndreyEgorov this was not working for me . And one more information these all are comes under parent tag so my code is y=i.find_elements_by_xpath('./div/div/div[@class="_4w5j"]/descendant::u')     So what will be xpath by css selector am new to here

Comment: @VivekSingh  Can you please help me for the text inside the u tag

Comment: find_element_by_tag_name('u').text show only the empty string new line. FYI that text was not displayed in the webpage

Comment: Isn't 5 star visible?

Comment: @VivekSingh No is not visible in the webpage

Answer (score 0):

```
i.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_4w5j"]/span//u')[0].text

i.find_elements_by_xpath('//a/abbr')[0].get_attribute('title')
```

Comment: For first one it print emptly only sir,                                                              For abbr it prints IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: No problem with text inside abbr but i need text inside the u tag

Comment: My typos. Try again pls.

Comment: I was confused by your random class names and now I edit again.

Comment: Anyway, my main points are 1. use // instead of descendant 2. attribute isn't an element

Answer (score 0):

Why do you stick with xpath?

Consider this

```
 find_element_by_tag_name('u').text         

 find_element_by_tag_name('abbr').get_attribute('title')
```

You have to adjust it to search for `elements` if you have multiple `u` and `abbr` tags.

Anyway this will be much more readable for you in future.

In may opinion you should not overuse `xpath` stuff, especially if you can get what you need with simpler methods like lookup by `tag_name` or `class` or `css_selector`

Comment: Yes I under stand the concept but why the  
find_element_by_tag_name('u').text show only the empty string new line.

Comment: only problem with a text inside u tag

Comment: FYI these all are child path